# Getting [ERROR] Invalid target definition! while specifying https://mysitename.com in Hydra Gtk

Tags: password-cracking, hydra

In Hydra-GTK, I've specified my target name as `https://example.com` (it's not www) and mentioned protocol as `https-post-form` and then entered username  and password list and then I started.
But I got this error message:

```
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) starting at 2018-01-05 01:06:43
[ERROR] Invalid target definition!
[ERROR] Either you use "www.example.com module [optional-module-parameters]" *or* you use the "module://www.example.com/optional-module-parameters" syntax!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should NOT put the `https://` part in your site parameter, see the following example:

```
hydra example.com http-form-post "/password.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:Bad login" -L users.txt -P pass.txt -t 10 -w 30 -o hydra-http-post-attack.txt
```

Comment: as per your suggestion, I made changes but now I'm getting following error:[ERROR] the variables argument needs at least the strings ^USER^ or ^PASS^: (null)..I hv alreday given reference to username and password as list named(username.txt, password.txt)..Please suggest what to do to get correct results.    Note: I've tried with single username and password, still it doesn't work. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please, share the exact command that you are executing in order to see the mistake on it.

Comment: I've not written this command, but it auto generate when I filled entries in hydra gtk..so, please find autogenerated query below:                           
hydra -v -V -L /root/Desktop/username.txt -P /root/Desktop/password.txt -t 16 -m /foo/bar/protected.html mysite.com https-post-form

Comment: I recommend you to use the command line, it's easier in that way, if you're getting that error, is because of the `-m /foo/bar/protected.html` parameter, you have to use something similar to my example, put in that field the URL of the target, the parameters USER and PASS and finally the success or fail case, good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried the same which you suggested and it worked. But it is giving me false results. In the uname and pwd list, there is 1 combination which is working . so, at the end, it displays    1 of 1 target successfully completed, 61 valid passwords found
Hydra (http://www.thc.org/thc-hydra) finished at 2018-01-08 00:27:06        It showing right that 1 of 1 target successful but not showing which one is the correct combination(username:password)..And I'm not able to understand why it is saying that 61 valid password found

Comment: Actually total combinations are 72(username:8, password:9). thanks

Comment: That error is because you are the mistake is in: `/password.php:user=^USER^&pass=^PASS^:Bad login` where is Bad Login, you have to put the error message of your website, otherwise, any attempt will be considered as successful.

Comment: Hello @Samy, I wrote a post on my personal blog explaining the process on how to use THC Hydra using both: CLI and GTK/GUI, hope it will be useful for you: [Cracking Passwords: Brute-force Attack with Hydra (CLI) + xHydra (GTK)](http://galogetlatorre.blogspot.com/2018/01/cracking-passwords-brute-force-thc-hydra-xhydra-gtk.html)

Comment: thanks for sharing your blog.really helpful..thanks!!!                        Actually the error message for my website(when wrong username/password is provided is->                                                  
Error: Cannot find user record.                                                                           The problem is when I put colon as mentioned in my website error message, it doesn't work. then I tried entering this error message in single quotes..then it gets hang. Please suggest how I specify my error message containing colon

Comment: Already updated my post explaining that scenario. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still getting the same issue :( it looks like it doesn't check what I've written in error message.

Comment: Please follow the steps explained in the post, check if the command is exactly the same, there is no reason for the tool to fail, read the Update section.